# Getting Access token is empty error while running msgraph-sdk-go training example code

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-api

While trying to run the msgraph-sdk-go training code from here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-go, I'm getting `InvalidAuthenticationTokenmsg: Access token is empty` while executing the Graph API calls.
I configured a Microsoft developer account with instant sandbox for trial purpose.
I created an app registration as mentioned in the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/go-app-only) and granted required permissions for the app.
The code is able to get the AppToken, but for calls to get Users, it fails with the above error. Am I missing something here?

[image: These are the permissions that are added currently in the app configuration]
I tried below code from the example for msgraph-training

```
func (g *GraphHelper) InitializeGraphForAppAuth() error {
    clientId := os.Getenv("CLIENT_ID")
    tenantId := os.Getenv("TENANT_ID")
    clientSecret := os.Getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
    credential, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    g.clientSecretCredential = credential

    
    // Create an auth provider using the credential
    authProvider, err := auth.NewAzureIdentityAuthenticationProviderWithScopes(g.clientSecretCredential, []string{
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Create a request adapter using the auth provider
    adapter, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphRequestAdapter(authProvider)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Create a Graph client using request adapter
    client := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(adapter)
    g.appClient = client

    return nil
}
// This part works, and I get the AppToken with required scope, once decoded.
func (g *GraphHelper) GetAppToken() (*string, error) {
    token, err := g.clientSecretCredential.GetToken(context.Background(), policy.TokenRequestOptions{
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("expires on : ", token.ExpiresOn)
    return &token.Token, nil
}

// The GetUsers function errors out
func (g *GraphHelper) GetUsers() (models.UserCollectionResponseable, error) {
    var topValue int32 = 25
    query := users.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters{
        // Only request specific properties
        Select: []string{"displayName", "id", "mail"},
        // Get at most 25 results
        Top: &topValue,
        // Sort by display name
        Orderby: []string{"displayName"},
    }

    resp, err := g.appClient.Users().
        Get(context.Background(),
            &users.UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration{
                QueryParameters: &query,
            })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Users.Get got Error", err.Error(), resp)
        printOdataError(err)
    }
    resp, err = g.appClient.Users().
        Get(context.Background(),
            nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Users.Get got Error with nil", err.Error(), resp)
    }
    return resp, err
}
```

I have added the `User.Read.All` permission in the app as mentioned in the tutorial.
Instead of getting the list of users, I'm getting below error:

```
Users.Get got Error error status code received from the API <nil>
error: error status code received from the API
code: InvalidAuthenticationTokenmsg: Access token is empty.Users.Get got Error with nil error status code received from the API <nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the fix that did work for me after trial and error was a version mismatch in the example and the actual application I was trying out.
The version of the beta msgraph application I was using was v0.49, whereas the msgraphsdk tutorial was using v0.48. The go mod command picked up the latest v0.49 initially I guess, I updated the `go.mod` file to use v0.48 after looking at the go.mod file from msgraph-training [repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-go) and things started working.
Hope this helps someone else later on.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using client Credential Flow ,you can verify your permission in azure portal , if you have User.Read.All delegated permission ,[image] Removes the delegated ones and add the corresponding application ones and don't forget to click on grant administrator consent after that. It should then work.

Hope this helps

Thanks.

Comment: @vicky_kumar Yeah, I do have the permissions configured for application type. Added a snap for that in the question, thanks.